# Error upgrading ruby version: undefined method `yaml_as'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I upgraded ruby version of my rails app from 2.2.1 to 2.5.1. However when I tried to start the rails server it gives me this error.

```
constant OpenSSL::SSL::SSLContext::METHODS is deprecated Traceback (most recent call last):     
25: from bin/rails:4:in `<main>'    
24: from bin/rails:4:in `require'   
23: from /home/jaydee/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/railties-4.2.10/lib/rails
  /commands.rb:17:in `<top (required)>'     
22: from /home/jaydee/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/railties-4.2.10/lib/rails
  /commands/commands_tasks.rb:39:in `run_command!'  
21: from /home/jaydee/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/railties-4.2.10/lib/rails
  /commands/commands_tasks.rb:75:in `server'    
20: from /home/jaydee/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/railties-4.2.10/lib/rails
  /commands/commands_tasks.rb:75:in `tap'   
19: from /home/jaydee/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/railties-4.2.10/lib/rails
  /commands/commands_tasks.rb:78:in `block in server'   
18: from /home/jaydee/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/railties-4.2.10/lib/rails
  /commands/commands_tasks.rb:78:in `require'   
17: from /home/jaydee/source/ruby-upgrade/shiftshark/config
  /application.rb:6:in `<top (required)>'   
16: from /home/jaydee/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/bundler-1.17.1
  /lib/bundler.rb:114:in `require'  
15: from /home/jaydee/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/bundler-1.17.1/lib/bundler
  /runtime.rb:65:in `require'   
14: from /home/jaydee/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/bundler-1.17.1/lib/bundler
  /runtime.rb:65:in `each'  
13: from /home/jaydee/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/bundler-1.17.1/lib/bundler
  /runtime.rb:76:in `block in require'  
12: from /home/jaydee/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/bundler-1.17.1/lib/bundler
  /runtime.rb:76:in `each'  
11: from /home/jaydee/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/bundler-1.17.1/lib/bundler
  /runtime.rb:81:in `block (2 levels) in require'   
10: from /home/jaydee/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/bundler-1.17.1/lib/bundler
  /runtime.rb:81:in `require'    
9: from /home/jaydee/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/delayed_job_active_record-
  4.0.3/lib/delayed_job_active_record.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'     
8: from /home/jaydee/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/delayed_job-4.0.6/lib
  /delayed/worker.rb:64:in `backend='    
7: from /home/jaydee/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/activesupport-4.2.10
  /lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:274:in `require'   
6: from /home/jaydee/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/activesupport-4.2.10
  /lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:240:in `load_dependency'   
5: from /home/jaydee/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/activesupport-4.2.10
  /lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:274:in `block in require'      
4: from /home/jaydee/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/activesupport-4.2.10
  /lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:274:in `require'   
3: from /home/jaydee/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/delayed_job-4.0.6/lib
  /delayed/serialization/active_record.rb:2:in `<top (required)>'    
2: from /home/jaydee/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/delayed_job-4.0.6/lib
  /delayed/serialization/active_record.rb:3:in `<module:ActiveRecord>'   
1: from /home/jaydee/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/delayed_job-4.0.6/lib
  /delayed/serialization/active_record.rb:4:in `<class:Base>'
/home/jaydee/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/activerecord-4.2.10
  /lib/active_record/dynamic_matchers.rb:26:in `method_missing': 
undefined method `yaml_as' for ActiveRecord::Base:Class (NoMethodError) 
Did you mean?  yaml_tag
```

Comment: I've updated the question title to mention the specific error. Also removed "rvm" because this can happen independently of rvm.

Answer (score 14):

Rails can't start because the `yaml_as` method doesn't exist any more (it was defined by the ruby built-in lib `psych`).

You need to update the version of `delayed_job`. See this [github issue](https://github.com/collectiveidea/delayed_job_active_record/issues/150#issuecomment-364272959).

Just run `bundle update delayed_job`.

Comment: I got new error after `require': cannot load such file -- sprockets/es6 (LoadError)

Comment: @Mr.Sinko check your `Gemfile` to make sure `sprockets-es6` is there.

Comment: got new error File to import not found or unreadable: foundation/functions.

Extracted source (around line #58):
@import 'foundation/functions';

gem 'rails', '< 5.0.0'
# Use SCSS for stylesheets
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 5.0.0'
gem 'foundation-rails'

Comment: @Mr.Sinko I encourage you to do some research on the error message (try Google) and try some of the solutions you find. If you're still having trouble, you can then post this as a *new* question on stackoverflow with information about what you've tried and what the results were.

Comment: Just as a follow-up, version 4.1.4 of `delayed_job` fixes this. See https://github.com/collectiveidea/delayed_job_active_record/issues/150#issuecomment-364265743